# How to add commands as shortcut on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using STS and guess its the same as Eclipse (*specific version posted below*). As every developer, I have to build my project multiple times (almost 40-50 times in a day). I do this in Debug mode and restart it on debug mode obviously for debugging purposes. Every time to do this simple thing, I have to:

1. Switch to Spring perspective (when I find that something is wrong when I am in Debug mode)
2. Select project
3. Right click on the project
4. Move my mouse cursor carefully to the next smaller window
5. Scroll and select "Maven Build"
6. *Then when build is successful*, I have to select the project, pick the small window and click "Debug on Server"

Though there are shortcut keys that shows up for this, its almost I have to use four-five fingers doesn't seem to me a shortcut.

Instead I would like to know if I can put up these two commands on the Eclipse' toolbar so that I can single click and/or set a shortcut as simple as Command + I (Debug Install) and Command + R (Debug Run)

Alternatively, if there's a command to do all of this in one click (or one shortcut key) that would be awesome.

```
Version:
Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.5.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201405030657
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an uninteresting question from my part. Sorry about it...

For anyone hitting this kind of requirement, I found a work around to set keys individually as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_a_keyboard_shortcut_for_my_action%3F). I also tried to as described in the SO post, but that did not work for me. I am settling to compromise with 3 set of frequently used keys.

The disadvantage is I still have to select/highlight the project on the left window. I had set command+1 for maven clean
command+2 for maven install
command+3 for debug on server

SpringToolSuite > Preferences > General > Keys 
Type the filter that you need and assign a command, make sure it does not conflict with another command using the key shortcut.

[image]